# TensorFlow 'module' object has no attribute 'global_variables_initializer'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, word2vec

I'm new to Tensorflow
I'm running a Deep learning Assignment from Udacity on iPython notebook.
[link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb)

And it has an error.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
`<ipython-input-18-3446420b5935>` in `<module>`()
  2 
  3 with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
----> 4   tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'global_variables_initializer'
```

Please help! How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In older versions, it was called `tf.initialize_all_variables`.

Answer (score 13):

Seems like you're using `tensorflow 0.11` or older versions. If you see this [git-commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/cbd3cacfb73bbea912b9d01c2540187684f751a7), they replaced `initialize_all_variables` with `global_variables_initializer`.

So, either you can use `initialize_all_variables` or update to a newer version i.e. (0.12) or later.

Comment: dir(tf) shows neither `initialize_all_variables` nor  `global_variables_initializer`

Answer (score 12):

In Tensorflow 2.0 , it does away from session and switches to eager execution. You can still run your code using session if you refer to tf.compat library and disable eager execution. This command should do the work:

```
tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow 1.11 You can use both initialize_all_variables().run() or tf.global_variables_initializer()

```
  #tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
```

both of then works fine on